# How to find all permutations of a single-direction path between nodes/sequence?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, permutation

***[Python 3.7]*** - **SEQUENCE POSSIBILITIES**

In trying to automate documentation from back-end code, I have a *"Sequence"* which consists of `steps` *(nodes)* and `transitions` *(paths)*. I want to cycle through all possibilities and consequently save all the possibilities in a nested list:

`[[seq_1],[seq_2],[seq_3]...[seq_n]`

This is a visual representation of what I am working with and what I would like to programmatically solve:

```
EXAMPLE:                              A________
                                      |   |    |   [A can have two paths to B]
                                      |___|    |
                                    __B        |
                                   |  |________|
                                   |  |  ^[This would connect to C from A]
                                   |  C
                                   |__|
                                      |
                                      D
```

**This should be the outcome:**

*NOTE: A1, A2 denotes different paths*

```
[[A1,B,C,D],[A2,B,C,D],[A1,B,D],[A2,B,D],[A,C,D]]
```

My initial attempt was to assign each node an array of optional nodes and to use a `for i in x` loop to run through each combination, I found this to not be very dynamic and not effective because of the paths skipping -- I could mitigate this with conditional if statements but I'd prefer to explore more dynamic options first.

This is what I had in mind as my initial attempt (in Pseudo Code):

```
Option Connections of Nodes:
A:[B1, B2, C]
B:[C, D]
C:[D]

Start at A:(and add to array)
   Loop through each possibility: (add to second element of array)
       loop through each possibility of A's possibility: (add to third element of array)
           ...
             after reaching D, save array and create next array.
```

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to find all paths between two nodes in a directed graph. Google this and you will find a lot of information about known algorithms to solve this problem: https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=2En&channel=fs&sxsrf=ALeKk01am9oUsQqEADRaEbiKWbwg0X2cKw%3A1582753896481&ei=aOhWXouFHYbc-gSykZmQDg&q=find+all+paths+between+two+nodes+python&oq=graph+algorithm+find+all+paths+between+two+nodes&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i71l8.0.0..5588...0.2..0.0.0.......0......gws-wiz.9ac7DrPXjSY

Comment: When there are two different edges from node A to node B, it is called a "multigraph".

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, Thank you - glad to find a relevant key-word - Have been so stuck with grid-style path finding results. I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: This is a very well known problem. Let me clarify some terminology so you can google about it more easily: A set of nodes with connections between the nodes is called a **graph**. The nodes are called **vertices**. The connections are called **edges**. A sequence of edges between two nodes is called a **path**. A graph with multiple edges between the same two nodes is called a **multigraph**. Hopefully these terms can help you devise a google search that will provide more information to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Fantastic - tonne's of help - Hopefully find a gem on the web.